# Can a MySQL 32bit database be imported/copied to a 64bit MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a database on a 32bit Linux server with MySQL that I would like to import/copy/migrate to a 64bit Linux server.

I have considered

```
service mysqld stop
tar czf /root/db.tar.gz /var/lib/mysql
```

and copy this to the new server.

Or perhaps

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > /root/db.sql
```

**Question**

Is that possible, and if so, what the recommended way?

Comment: Copying all the files almost certainly won't work. The second option certainly will (given the right options on both servers), although it may take a long time. Your best bet is probably a purpose built backup tool. What database engine are you using?

Comment: InnoDB's data file format is independent of the platform, and if you copy the data correctly from the source and put it into the correct place with the correct permissions on the destination, there will be no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mysqldump` and re-importing the resultant file will work for certain and is recommended, unless your database is very large and the dump/import process' slower speed is an issue.

Unless the server environment is identical in most ways, you may have some cleaning up to do and permissions corrections if you were to copy the data files over directly.  [There is documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-rawdata.html) on performing the transfer with raw data files, but `mysqldump` is the usual preferred method.

Comment: A dump and reload is actually more likely to cause some kind of problem by converting the data from the on-disk format to SQL, then converting it back to the on-disk format.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large database, I would suggest using [XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/). It will likely be much faster than using `mysqldump` followed by an import.